# Ajax in Laravel 8 does not return data

Tags: ajax, laravel-8

I am fairly new to Lavarel 8 and Ajax and I have been trying to write a simple test. The code is largely working without any errors from either Laravel or Javascript, but it doesn't seem to return any data.

The following are my routes in web.php:

```
Route::get('foo', [mainController::class, 'foo']);
Route::get('get_foo', [mainController::class, 'get_foo']);
```

The following is in my controller:

```
  public function foo() {
    return view('foo');
  }

  public function get_foo() {
    return "this is not a test";
  }
```

The following is my blade (foo.blade.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
          headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          },
            method : 'GET', 
            url : "get_foo",
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(result){
              console.log("The result is --> %o", result);
            }
        });
    }); 
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

What it should do is to print "the result is --> this is not a test" at the developer's console, however I am not getting any output. The console shows a success XHR message so I am assuming the Ajax works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I stumbled on the answer after more searching on the Net. I cannot just return an answer. I need to let Laravel know that I am replying to a Ajax request with a call to the Response object, like so:

```
  public function get_foo() {
    return Response() -> json("this is not a test");
  }
}
```

Now my console displays the output correctly.